# Redux Reducer Uses Data From When I last Logged In

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux

I want to implement Editing a user with Redux in my project. I created an EDIT_USER reducer which works ok. I can trigger the respective action and this reducer from anywhere inside the application.
Say I wanted to change the header color (the header component is really high in the component tree) from a button inside a card compoment (which is really low in the component tree). It works. However, whenever I refresh the page, the header's color is the color it was when the user last logged in! This is my SET_CURRENT_USER reducer:

```
    case SET_CURRENT_USER:
        return {
            isAuthenticated: Object.keys(action.user).length > 0,
            user: action.user
        };
```

This is in App.js, which triggers the SET_CURRENT_USER reducer, through the setCurrentUser action:

```
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  setAuthorizationToken(localStorage.jwtToken);
  try {
    store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(jwtDecode(localStorage.jwtToken)));
  }
  catch (e) {
    store.dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));
  }
}
```

My expected behaviour is the following.
1. User logs in, header is blue (default color). ----OK
2. User changes the header color to green, through the button that triggers de EDIT_USER reducer. ----OK
3. Immediately the header changes to green. ---OK
4. I refresh the page and the header is still green. ----NOT OK (it shows blue, because that was the color when the user last logged in).
5. When I sign out and log in again, the header turns green. ----OK (this is expected, but point 4 is the main issue!)

If you need any further details please let me know! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have a persister setup for your redux? I assume so... If you do use the `onBeforeLift` to reset any values you don't want to keep before it persists the state.

Comment: Not aware of that, you mean something about redux persist? Could you explain a bit more? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Can you add how you configure your store for your redux? Are you using redux-persist anywhere? If you can let me know what libraries you are using then I can put an example specific to those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I configure my store:

```
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';  
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose  } from 'redux';  
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';  

export function configureStore(){  
  const store = createStore(  
    rootReducer,  
    compose(  
      applyMiddleware(thunk),  
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f
  ));  

  return store;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it never persisted in the store. Your previous `state` values are lost since it wasn't returned in the reducer.

Try this:

```
case SET_CURRENT_USER:
    return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: Object.keys(action.user).length > 0,
        user: action.user
    };
```